# 'pytesseract.pytesseract' has no attribute 'pytesseract' - Attribute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I am using Spyder4 for python.
I have done almost all the required things:

1. Installed pytesseract package using (!pip install --user pytesseract)
2. Downloaded and installed Tessaract-ocr and my tessaract.exe location is  (C:\Users**\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe)
3. I have added the same location(tessaract-ocr) in Path Environment variables

still i am getting the error like "AttributeError: module 'pytesseract.pytesseract' has no attribute 'pytesseract' "

The following is my code

```
from passporteye import read_mrz
from pytesseract import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Users\\*<username>*\\AppData\\Local\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

# Process image
mrz = read_mrz("C:\\Users\\*<username>*\\Documents\\UiPath\\imageExtract\\Data\\image1.jpeg")


# Obtain image
mrz_data = mrz.to_dict()

# Printing extracted data
print('Nationality :'+ mrz_data['nationality'])
print('Given Name :'+ mrz_data['names'])
print('Surname :'+ mrz_data['surname'])
print('Passport type :'+ mrz_data['type'])
print('Date of birth :'+ mrz_data['date_of_birth'])
print('ID Number :'+ mrz_data['personal_number'])
print('Gender :'+mrz_data['sex'])
print('Expiration date :'+ mrz_data['expiration_date'])
```

What i am expecting is 'After successful execution the code should display the feilds extracted from image' but continuously i am getting the same error Attribute not found.

Please help me in solving the above problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you run `tesseract.exe` in terminal to get the results from the image?

Answer (score 0):

You import is wrong, you can change it like.

**Option1:**

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract as PT 


PT.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text_from_image = PT.image_to_string(Image.open('test_image.png'))
print(text_from_image)
```

**Option 2:**

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
text_from_image = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test_image.png'))
print(text_from_image)
```